# How to set number as row name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, ddl, create-table

In SQLite, I want to create a table with row name as numbers like 
1 , 2, 3 ,4

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERTABLE ( 1 INTEGER , 2 INTEGER , 3 INTEGER ) ;
```

but it doesnt work .

I searched over the Internet but I couldn't find the solution.
Can anyone show me how to do this ?

Comment: Back-ticks, but why?

Comment: Please don't do this... This makes querying the table much more troublesome than it should be.

Comment: Can u give me the create statement ?

Comment: You better rethink your design because it's __most likely__ wrong. Also, do some googling, @jarlh has already provided you with solution.

Comment: As @jarlh said , wrap each column name with back ticks : ` , but.. DON'T.

Comment: Thanks .I will avoid this..

Comment: Your title says "mysql", your question and tags say "sqlite" ... which? (Not that you should do it in either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are column names, not row names. MySQL allows you to use backticks to escape column names, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE numbertable (`1` INTEGER, `2` INTEGER, `3` INTEGER);
```

But this is more often than not a recipe for bugs later on. It would be much easier to just use valid column names. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE numbertable (col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER, col3 INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE o_god_please_dont_do_this ( `1` INTEGER, `2` INTEGER...);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the syntax :

`CREATE TABLE 'numbertable' ('column1' INTEGER, 'column2' INTEGER, 'column3' INTEGER);`

But naming a column with a number isn't a really good option ... naming like "column1" is already better, that is to avoid some bugs.